# Using rosdep to install WG maintained stacks

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-fuerte, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to package some of my robot's stack it's easier to get running on a base installation of ROS-Desktop-Full. In particular, my stack depends on several stacks that aren't installed by default (e.g. `prosilica_camera`, `laser_drivers`, etc). These stacks are developed by Willow, so there are debs available (i.e. `ros-fuerte-prosilica-camera`, `ros-fuerte-laser-drivers`, etc) and it works fine if I manually install the debs.

I thought `rosdep` would handle this (i.e. `rosdep install my_stack`), but it doesn't detect any missing dependencies. Is `rosdep` the right tool to do this? If not, is there another way of achieving this type dependency resolution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34984/using-rosdep-to-install-wg-maintained-stacks/) by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 524 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install those stacks apt-get install ros-fuerte-stack-name is the way to install them with all their dependencies.  rosdep installs system dependencies of source packages in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No you can't.

But I +1 this request.
I have always found awkward the fact that rosdep can basically find any dependency it requires except the one which are "under control" and which should be the easiest to install automatically...

Why not enhancing rosdep so that it suggests a system package when possible?

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2012-06-06**:
I'm glad I'm not the only one who was looking for this feature. It would be very nice if this functionality was added to rosdep.